# Netty Channels closing while trying to replace TLS Certificates

Tags: ssl, netty

My project uses the Netty framework to create Channel with SslHandlers that use TLS to enable node to node encryption. I'm trying to replace expired TLS Certs with new ones.

I'm able to replace the current SSLHandler with a new one containing the new certificates using -

```
pipeline.replace(sslhandler, SSL_HANDLER_NAME, newSSLHandler);
```

My issue is that this step closes pre-existing channels associated with this pipeline and creates new ones. Any way I can replace the handler without the channels closing?

Comment: So you want to do a handshake again with the new certificates without closing the existing connection ?

Comment: Exactly, Is that possible? How would I go about doing it?

Comment: I did not try it but I guess you could use `sslHandler.close()` on the used instance and once this is closed add a new `SslHandler` to the pipeline

Comment: Tried this but looks like the existing connections are still closing. I figured closing the channel and re-creating it may be the best course of action since I don't want plaintext messages to be transmitted by mistake.